# Android set TextView from other class

Tags: android, textview

I have code:

```
LinearLayout primaryFieldsView = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);
        for(int j=0; j<5; j++){
             TextView text = new TextView(this);
             text.setText("The Value of i is :"); // <-- does it really compile without the + sign?
             text.setTextSize(12);  
             text.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
             text.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
             primaryFieldsView.addView(text);
            }
```

I would like to that this code was called from another class, for example:
In main class:

```
new PrimaryFieldsView().setPrimaryFields();
```

Other class:

```
public class PrimaryFieldsView extends Activity{

    public void setPrimaryFields(){

        LinearLayout primaryFieldsView = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);
        for(int j=0; j<5; j++){
             TextView text = new TextView(this);
             text.setText("The Value of i is :"); // <-- does it really compile without the + sign?
             text.setTextSize(12);  
             text.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
             text.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
             primaryFieldsView.addView(text);
            }



    }
```

When i put this code in Main class that work:

```
        LinearLayout primaryFieldsView = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);
        for(int j=0; j<5; j++){
             TextView text = new TextView(this);
             text.setText("The Value of i is :"); // <-- does it really compile without the + sign?
             text.setTextSize(12);  
             text.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
             text.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
             primaryFieldsView.addView(text);
            }
```

At this moment i have error

```
10-27 21:32:58.389: E/AndroidRuntime(2907): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.passreader/com.example.passreader.views.CouponView}: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public void setPrimaryFields(Activity activity)
    {
        LinearLayout primaryFieldsView = (LinearLayout) activity.findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);
        for(int j=0; j<5; j++){
            TextView text = new TextView(this);
            text.setText("The Value of i is :"); // <-- does it really compile without the + sign?
            text.setTextSize(12);  
            text.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
            text.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            primaryFieldsView.addView(text);
           }
    }
```

in main:

```
setPrimaryFields(this);
```

PrimaryFieldsView class does not have to extend anything though.

Comment: did not help, error: 10-27 22:04:19.759: E/AndroidRuntime(2981): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.passreader/com.example.passreader.views.CouponView}: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Does that work:)Now i have:public class PrimaryFieldsView{
 
 public void setPrimaryFields(Activity activity){
  
  LinearLayout primaryFieldsView = (LinearLayout) activity.findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);
  for(int j=0; j<5; j++){
       TextView text = new TextView(primaryFieldsView.getContext());...it's ok?

Comment: ty, It's ok to have another class to add those textview if you are going to use it in another activity otherwise, you don't have to do it in a separated class.